# Error while implementing currency converter of yahoo

Tags: php

```
<?php   error_reporting(0); 
    $currency_code = $_GET['currency_code'];    
    $currency_opt = strtoupper($currency_code)."INR";   
    $jsn_response = file_get_contents('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20%28%22' .$currency_opt. '%22%29&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback='); 

    $currencyrate_arr = json_decode($jsn_response, true);

    $currency_rate = $currencyrate_arr['query']['results']['rate']['Rate']; 
    //var_dump($currency_rate);
    if($currency_rate > 0){     
        echo $currency_text = $currency_rate;   
    }
    else{       
        echo $currency_text = "SORRY! ERROR..";     
    }
?>
```

It was working fine but now I am getting error while using this piece of code for currency conversion.

Comment: Tell us what error you get...

Comment: 1 GBP = Warning: file_get_contents(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /homeb/home/arpan/www/donate/cur_conv.php on line 6 Warning: file_get_contents(http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20%28%22GBPINR%22%29&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /homeb/home/arpan/www/donate/cur_conv.php on line 6 SORRY! ERROR.. INR

Answer (score 0):

The script is working for me, and produces correct results.

If you are receiving an error, it's either because of a server configuration, or an API limit.

You can check https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/faq/

> Rate limits in YQL are based on your authentication. If you use IP-based authentication, then you are limited to 2,000 calls/hour/IP to the public YQL Web service URL (/v1/public/*)

If you need to exceed the 2000 calls per hour limit, read the above link for more information.

**PS:** If you want to debug, set:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**Edit**: Since `allow_url_fopen` is disabled, you can't use `file_get_contents` on outside URLs, but you can still use CURL.

So just replace the `file_get_contents` with:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20%28%22' .$currency_opt. '%22%29&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$jsn_response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: 1 GBP = Warning: file_get_contents(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /homeb/home/arpan/www/donate/cur_conv.php on line 6 Warning: file_get_contents(http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20%28%22GBPINR%22%29&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /homeb/home/arpan/www/donate/cur_conv.php on line 6 SORRY! ERROR.. INR